# create a dynamic html page with jinja in fastAPI

Tags: python, html, jinja2, fastapi

I want to create a dynamic html page with fastAPI and jinja2.
for example my python code is this:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="/htmlfiles")

@app.get("/home/{name}", response_class=HTMLResponse)
def read_item(request: Request, name: str):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("test.html", {"request": Request, "name": name})
```

and my html is this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>hello this is a test page</h1>
    <p>welcome ... {{name}}</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

but when I use uvicorn and connect to page raise Internal error (statuscode = 500)

Comment: Don't you have the actual error traceback in the console?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 1):

- try: `Request` -> `request`

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="/htmlfiles")

@app.get("/home/{name}", response_class=HTMLResponse)
def read_item(request: Request, name: str):
    return templates.TemplateResponse(
        "test.html", {"request": request, "name": name}
    )
```

Comment: oh my god ! I can't believe that I was left with a ridiculous error. thank you very much for your help.